# problema con arrays

Tags: php

Me gustaría saber porqué ocurre esto:

$c[0]='a';
$c[0][0]='b';

hasta aquí todo bien, pero si agrego

$c[0][0][0]='c';

da el error
Fatal error: Cannot use string offset as an array in H:\aNoti\web\work\miniforo\pb.php on line 3

Answer (score 0):

Varias cosas:

1. Tu primera asignación: `$c[0]='a';` crea un array, y le agrega el valor `a` en la primera posición.

   Probemos:

   ```
   $c[0]='a';
   var_dump($c);
   ```

   Resultado:

   ```
   array(1) {
     [0]=>
     string(1) "a"
   }
   ```
2. En cambio, tu segunda asignación **reemplaza** ese valor. Veamos:

   ```
   $c[0]='a';
   $c[0][0]='b';
   var_dump($c);
   ```

   Resultado:

   ```
   array(1) {
     [0]=>
     string(1) "b"
   }
   ```

   Como podrás apreciar, no agregaste un segundo valor a tu array, sino que reemplazaste el valor de `a` introducido previamente.
3. Al hacer esto: `$c[0][0][0]='c';` tienes el **error**:

> Uncaught Error: Cannot use string offset as an array

¿Qué tal si vemos qué es realmente `$c[0][0][0]`? Veamos:

```
    $c[0]='a';
    $c[0][0]='b';
    var_dump($c[0][0][0]);

Resultado:

    string(1) "b"
```

Entonces lo que te dice el error es que `$c[0][0][0]` es un string, cuyo valor es `b` y no puedes usarlo como un array, que es lo que intentas... introducir `c` en una posición determinada del array.

---

Varias soluciones:

#### Array de una dimensión

```
    $c[0]='a';
    $c[1]='b';
    $c[2]='c';  
    print_r($c);
```

Resultado:

```
    Array
    (
        [0] => a
        [1] => b
        [2] => c
    )
```

**Nota:** La construcción se puede hacer también en este estilo:

```
    $c=array('a','b','c');
```

#### Array de dos dimensiones

```
    $c[0][0]='a';
    $c[0][1]='b';
    $c[0][2]='c';  
    print_r($c);
```

Resultado:

```
    Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => a
                [1] => b
                [2] => c
            )

    )
```

#### Array de tres dimensiones

**Con cada valor en un array aparte:**

```
$c[0][0][0]='a';
$c[1][0][0]='b';
$c[2][0][0]='c';  
print_r($c);
```

Resultado:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => a
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => b
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => c
                )

        )

)
```

**Con los tres valores en el mismo array:**

```
    $c[0][0][0]='a';
    $c[0][0][1]='b';
    $c[0][0][2]='c';  
    print_r($c);
```

Resultado:

```
    Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => a
                        [1] => b
                        [2] => c
                    )

            )

    )
```